How to prove a isometry is a linear transform
A $C^\infty$ bijection $x\to\widetilde{x}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial\tilde x_k}{\partial {x}_i} \frac{\partial\tilde x_k}{\partial {x}_j} = \delta_{ij} $$
which means that the Jacobian is an orthogonal matrix. How to prove that this map is linear, or equivalently that the Jacobian is invariant?
I have proved the $n=2$ case by assuming that The Jacobian takes the form
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta(x_1,x_2),&\sin\theta(x_1,x_2)\\
-\sin\theta(x_1,x_2),&\cos\theta(x_1,x_2)
\end{pmatrix}$$
or
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta(x_1,x_2),&-\sin\theta(x_1,x_2)\\
\sin\theta(x_1,x_2),&\cos\theta(x_1,x_2)
\end{pmatrix}$$
and applying the interchange property of double partial derivatives. I don't know if this works for the general case, or there is a better way to prove this. Need some help.

The map is not linear but affine. You should start by observing that it maps geodesics to geodesics and preserves distances.

See p. 114 of my differential geometry text (freely linked in my profile). This is just linear algebra and is a fact about isometrics with no differentiability mentioned.

In particular, it's better to use the fact that if $F: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is an isomety, then for any $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$,  $$ |F(x_1)-F(x_2)|^2 = |x_1-x_2|^2. $$ You need no additional assumptions, but note that this assumption implies continuity.

This is a question I had when I read a physics book, in which a "rotation" in Euclidean space is defined as a coordinate transformation $ x \to \tilde{x} $ from $ \mathbb{R}^n $ to $ \mathbb{R}^n $, which satisfies the condition that its Jacobian is an orthogonal matrix. It also writes: "It can be proven that rotations in Euclidean space are linear coordinate transformations," meaning that the Jacobian matrix is a constant matrix (more precisely, it should be a rigid body transformation). I don't know differential geometry well, sorry if my nouns made some misunderstandings.
I followed my original approach and found a proof like this(see https://mathoverflow.net/a/228969):
Without loss of generality, we can prove the case when $ x = 0 $, and we may assume $ \tilde{x}(0) = 0 $ and the Jacobian matrix is the identity matrix. If this is not the case, we can always perform another rigid body transformation on the new coordinates to satisfy these conditions. Clearly, the new transformation will still satisfy the condition of having an orthogonal Jacobian.
Thus, we have the Taylor expansion:
$$
\tilde{x}_i(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = x_i + Q^{(i)}_{kl} x_k x_l + (\text{higher-order terms}).
$$
Here, $ Q^{(m)} $ is the Hessian matrix of $ \tilde{x}_m(x) $ at $ 0 $.
Differentiating the above expression and keeping only the linear terms, the $ (i,j)$-th element of the Jacobian matrix is
$$
\delta_{ij} + 2 Q^{(j)}_{ik} x_k.
$$
From the orthogonality condition of the Jacobian matrix (still keeping only the linear terms), we get:
$$
\delta_{jl} + 2Q_{jk}^{(l)}x_k + 2Q_{lk}^{(j)}x_k = \delta_{jl} \implies (Q_{jk}^{(l)} + Q_{lk}^{(j)})x_k = 0.
$$
Since $ x $ can be chosen arbitrarily, we obtain
$$
Q_{jk}^{(i)} + Q_{ik}^{(j)} = 0.
$$
Given the above and the symmetry of the Hessian matrix, we have
$$
Q^{(i)}_{jk} = -Q^{(j)}_{ik} = -Q^{(j)}_{ki} = Q^{(k)}_{ji} = Q^{(k)}_{ij} = -Q^{(i)}_{kj} = -Q^{(i)}_{jk},
$$
which implies $ Q^{(i)}_{jk} = 0 $.
The Hessian matrix being zero means that the partial derivatives of the Jacobian matrix are all zero, thus proving that the Jacobian matrix of this transformation is a constant matrix!
